# .isHardwareDetected() does not execute

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I want to implement a Fingerprint sensor verification function for android. So I implemented this Java function, which is called by other one:

```
public boolean checkSensor (){
   Context context=this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(); 
   FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
   // runs like a charm
   boolean abc = fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected();
   // doesn't reach this step. function is terminated with error
   return abc;
   }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: "function is terminated with error" suggests that you get an error message. Please post your error message!

Comment: this function is caller inside a cordova.exec(success, failure, service, action, [args]). When I say it ends with an error, it is because after that step the failure function is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already managed to figure it out. It was a problem with the User Permissions (not edited correctly on the plugin.xml).

Just add

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
</config-file>
```

under the  and it runs like a charm.